# Почему удваивает скобку двойную?

Tags: c

Цель кода: чтобы удалял комментарии (//; /**/)

с 10 по 19 строчку есть ошибка печатает лишнюю скобку и не стирает комментарий типа /**/ на строке 21(input), подскажите как исправить?
сам код input не несет в себе ни какой логики, он нужен что бы проверить правильность моей проги
основной код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
int main() {
    int c, v = 0;
    FILE* in, * out;
    fopen_s(&in, "input.c", "r"); 
    fopen_s(&out, "out.c", "w"); 
    while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) 
    {
        if (c == '\"') { //-10 строка
            putc(c, out);
            c = fgetc(in);
            while ((c != '\"') && (c != EOF)) {
                fputc(c, out);
                c = fgetc(in);
            }
            fputc(c, out);
            c = fgetc(in);
            fputc(c, out); //- 19 строка
        }
        if (c == '/') {
            c = fgetc(in);
            if (c == '/') {
                v = fgetc(in);
                while ((c = fgetc(in)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
                fputc('\n', out);
                
            }
            else if (c == '*') {
                while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
                    if (c == '/' && v == '*')
                        break;
                    v = c;
                }
                if ((c != '/') && (v != '*') && (c != EOF))
                    fputc(c, out);
            }
            else if (c == EOF)
                break;
            else
            {
                fputc('/', out);
                fputc(c, out);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            fputc(c, out);
        }
        
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
int main() {
    int m = 6, m1 = 4;
    //waaaaasd
   //if (M1[1] > 0) printf("incorrect");
           /*if ((M[0] == 0 && M1[0] == 2)) {
               printf("%d%d.", dd[0], dd[1]);
               for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
                   printf("%c", mm2[c]);
               }
               printf(".%d", yy);
           }*/
    puts("hiiii\/* */"); //- вот здесь последняя скобка удваивается 
    char c; // NS\
    NS2\
    NS3
    char* p = "\///*a\"sd*/\
    \
    \"
        /*NS4*/ char S; /*NS5*/ char S2; //21 строка почему то здесь не стирает комментарий
    
    m / m1;

}
```

Comment: Да потому что после того, как вы выводите `"hiiii\/* */"`, зачем-то прочитываете и выводите следующий символ (в нашем случае `')'`): `c = fgetc(in); fputc(c, out); //- 19 строка`. Далее у вас следует `if (c == '/') {...} else {fputc(c, out);}` - т.е., вы опять выводите этот же символ `')'`! А не стирает комментарий на 21-й строке потому, что у вас имеется незакрытый символ `"` на строке 20-й (зелёная подсветка вашего же примера как бы намекает). В целом же код ужасен - его проще переписать с нуля, чем исправить. Не в обиду будет сказано))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему ваш код не работает, я написал в комментарии. И дабы не быть голословным (насчёт "переписать с нуля"), привожу свой вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum STATE
{
    IN_REGULAR_TEXT,
    IN_STRING,
    IN_COMMENT_START,
    IN_SINGLELINE_COMMENT,
    IN_MULTILINE_COMMENT,
    IN_COMMENT_END
};

int main() 
{
    int c;
    FILE *in,*out;
    STATE s;

    in = fopen("input.c", "r"); 
    out = fopen("out.c", "w"); 

    s = IN_REGULAR_TEXT;
    while (true) 
    {
        c = fgetc(in);

        switch (s)
        {
        case IN_REGULAR_TEXT:
            if (c=='"')
            {
                fputc(c, out);
                s = IN_STRING;
                continue;
            }
            if (c=='/')
            {
                s = IN_COMMENT_START;
                continue;
            }
            if (c==EOF) break;

            fputc(c, out);
            continue;

        case IN_STRING:
            if (c==EOF)
            {
                puts("ERROR: unexpected end of file (in string)");
                break;
            }

            fputc(c, out);

            if (c=='"')
            {
                s = IN_REGULAR_TEXT;
                continue;
            }

            if (c=='\n')
            {
                puts("ERROR: unexpected end of line (in string)");
                s = IN_REGULAR_TEXT;
            }
            continue;

        case IN_COMMENT_START:
            if (c=='/')
            {
                s = IN_SINGLELINE_COMMENT;
                continue;
            }
            if (c=='*')
            {
                s = IN_MULTILINE_COMMENT;
                continue;
            }

            fputc('/', out);
            if (c==EOF) break;

            fputc(c, out);
            s = IN_REGULAR_TEXT;
            continue;

        case IN_SINGLELINE_COMMENT:
            if (c==EOF) break;
            if (c=='\n')
            {
                fputc(c, out);
                s = IN_REGULAR_TEXT;
            }
            continue;

        case IN_MULTILINE_COMMENT:
            if (c==EOF)
            {
                puts("WARNING: unecpected end of file (in multiline comment)");
                break;
            }
            if (c=='*') s = IN_COMMENT_END;
            continue;

        case IN_COMMENT_END:
            if (c==EOF)
            {
                puts("WARNING: unecpected end of file (in multiline comment)");
                break;
            }
            if (c='/')
            {
                s = IN_REGULAR_TEXT; 
                continue;
            }

            if (c!='*') s = IN_MULTILINE_COMMENT;
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Будет выведено в out.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
int main() {
    int m = 6, m1 = 4;
    
   
           
    puts("hiiii\/* */"); 
    char c; 
    NS2\
    NS3
    char* p = "\///*a\"sd*/\
    \
    \"
         char S;  char S2; 
    
    m / m1;

}
```

Будет выведено в консоль:

```
ERROR: unexpected end of line (in string)
```

Comment: На первый взгляд нормально, толко (по крайней мере в gcc) single line комментарий  продолжается на следующей строке, если в конце строки находится символ `\\` (даже если после него идут whitespaces)

Comment: @avp Для этого код легко модифицировать. Добавляем ещё одно состояние, назовём его `IN_SINGLELINE_COMMENT_NEXTLINE`. В него будет переход из состояния `IN_SINGLELINE_COMMENT` при чтении символа`'\\'`. В этом состоянии мы прерываем цикл при чтении `EOF` (break), ничего не делаем (continue) при чтении `' '`, `'\x9'`, `'\\'`, переходим обратно в `IN_SINGLELINE_COMMENT` в остальных случаях. Полагаю, есть смысл оставить автору для самостоятельной доработки...

Comment: Добавлю ещё, что мой код не учитывает возможного наличия символов `'\"'` внутри строки. Поправить это так же легко (плюс дополнительное состояние при чтении символа `'\\'` внутри строки).